# How to play Notification sound when user is talking on phone?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm developing an app which detecting BLE signal from specific beacons continuously. The content of the signal will be changed if the batteries of these beacons are going to die. As a result, I can prompt the user that which beacon is going to die and he or she may need to change or recharge its battery.

I put the detection in Service and in general situation it just works perfectly. No matter the app is in foreground or background, the app will send a notification to the user with vibration and sound as long as the app detects abnormal signals. The following is the setting of `Notification` in my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
       .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
       .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
       .setSound(sound)
       .setVibrate(new long[]{INTERVAL_VIBRATE, INTERVAL_VIBRATE});

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    builder.setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
}

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
    builder.setContentText(message);
}

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

**Here comes the problem:**

When the user is talking on the phone he or she will receive notifications, as well as vibrations. But **cannot receive notification sound**, I would like to know if there is a way to accomplish this feature.

Comment: I doubt that someone wants to get a notification sound while speaking on their phone. Just saying.

Comment: @H.Brooks this app is used for monitoring emergency events signals generated by beacons which are installed in a room or a vehicle. If something happened, the user needs to be notified.

Comment: Did you try looking at the priority field? Another thing is try looking at headsup notifications may profile some insight.

Comment: @JoxTraex Thanks for your reply. I would like to know how to find the priority field? Headup notification did providing some informations, but when users is speaking on phone, he or she may not take a look on his/her screen

Comment: The thing is that you will have to layer the notification sound on top. Using `RingtoneManager` you will have to set  `setStreamType` which is deprecated. You can use `TelephonyManager` to check the state of the call. But like I said, I would not recommend this, even if it is a emergency notification, rather use a more aggressive vibration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out an alternative solution: use `ToneGenerator` to play sound.

In this case, when I use only `Notification`, the sound of the notification disappeared when I'm on phone, even though the vibration still works, I want to find an advanced way to prompt the user that he or she is needed to beware of something.

So, in my service, I add `PhoneStateListener` to monitor my phone state

```
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = createPhoneStateListener();
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

my createPhoneStateListener() method:

```
private PhoneStateListener createPhoneStateListener() {
    return new PhoneStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            switch(state){
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE :
                    isUserSpeakingOnPhone = false;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING :
                    isUserSpeakingOnPhone = true;
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK :
                    isUserSpeakingOnPhone = true;
                    break;
            }
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        }
    };
}
```

I use a boolean **isUserSpeakingOnPhone** to determine if I need to start an `IntentService` which called `PlayToneService` to generate tones and play at the same time when I need to push a notification:

```
if (isUserSpeakingOnPhone) {
        Intent playTone = new Intent(this, PlayToneService.class);
        startService(playTone);

}
```

PlayToneService.class:

```
public class PlayToneService extends IntentService {

    public PlayToneService() {
        super(PlayToneService.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

        // play tone
        try {
            ToneGenerator toneGenerator= new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, ToneGenerator.MAX_VOLUME);
            toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
            Thread.sleep(200);
            toneGenerator.stopTone();
            toneGenerator.release();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when the user is speaking on phone and receives a notification, instead of a notfication sound, he/she will hear the "beep" sound from device's speaker. When the user is not speaking on phone, the notification sound will work as usual.